# How to implement Session Tracking in spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session

I am very new to spring mvc, I have to develop a web application based on session tracking and my application is annotation based. In my web app I have route each page based on the username and role existence in session. Initially I have been using HttpSession as parameter to controller method, but it is very difficult to check each and every request. I know there are many application level security ways in spring, but I really couldn't understand how to use them. Please suggest me some solutions, For all help thanks in advance.

After updating with interceptors:

```
  Controller class

  // Method to showLogin page to user
@RequestMapping(value = "user")
public ModelAndView showLoginToUser(@ModelAttribute("VMFE") VmFeUser VMFE,HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("@C====>showLoginToUser()===> ");
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
    //session.setAttribute("user_name", "no_user");
    try {
        view.setViewName("login");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return view;
}

  Interceptor

  public class HelloWorldInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
   @Override
public boolean preHandle (HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response,
                          Object handler) throws Exception {
    RequestMapping rm = ((HandlerMethod) handler).getMethodAnnotation(
                        RequestMapping.class);

    boolean alreadyLoggedIn = request.getSession()
                                     .getAttribute("user_name") != null;
    boolean loginPageRequested = rm != null && rm.value().length > 0
                                          && "login".equals(rm.value()[0]);


    if (alreadyLoggedIn && loginPageRequested) {
        //response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/app/main-age");
        return false;
    } else if (!alreadyLoggedIn && !loginPageRequested) {
        System.out.println("REDIRECTING===");
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/user");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: I dont realy understand what you are trying to do but you can make a bean session scoped using this @Scope(value="session")

Comment: I need to check session variable existence for each request.

Comment: Ah okay. First thing that comes into my mind is to use an session scoped bean that holds all the values you need and because it is bound to the session there is no need to access the HttpSession

Comment: could you please show some example on how to approach my requirement?

Comment: you could try **Interceptor** for that purpose, google it for **Spring Session Interceptor**, Or have a look at [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-handler-interceptor)

Comment: That Interceptor idea from @ShantaramTupe is exactly what you are looking for I guess. With an Interceptor you have exactly one place to implement you logic for checking the existance of variables. I think the following link would point you into the right direction of how to do it: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-model-parameters-with-handler-interceptor

Comment: I have added interceptor concept in my web app, but it is calling continuously. I have updated my code above.

Answer (score -1):

Using spring security you can implement session tracking and apply filters to validate requests. Spring security is very easy to implement. Kindly follow spring security tutorial [click here](https://www.dineshonjava.com/spring-security-take-baby-step-to-secure/).
You can also check my git repo for implementation [click here](https://github.com/paras16jul1991/angular-tour-of-heros). It's a angular spring boot application and  i have used spring security and JWT for authentication and authorization.

Hope it helps you thanks.